# gcloud compute same instance data not shown

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm using google cloud compute from past 2 months. Recently I gave access to new members of the team.

I have given them `editor` access. But they can't see the data files or any files already present in the same google compute instance.
When they do `ls` command, no files are shown though there are files that are already there.

They logged in from a different mail id and have created own passphrase.

But `df -h` command shows that

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             15G     0   15G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G  9.0M  3.0G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        49G   20G   29G  41% /
tmpfs            15G  108K   15G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.0G   24K  3.0G   1% /run/user/114
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /run/user/1002
```

How can the other users logged in with different mail id use the data alrealy there on gcloud instance?

Comment: If they can login to the google compute instance, each one should have their proper home directory and each one can't access the other home directory, you can create a group assign  this group read and write permission to the shared folder or file, then add these you user to the group.

Comment: So, you mean to say each one has different home directory and it's not seen by others though being the admin?

Comment: Each one will have their proper home directory as a workplace, each one cannot access the other user home directory, unless if he has the root permission or permission to access that folder (home directory)

Comment: Oh, then how to make collaboration folder such that each one can view other's work?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a group assign this group read and write permission to the shared folder, then add these users to the group [here](https://www.tecmint.com/create-a-shared-directory-in-linux/)